# How to fix "No such file or directory" error in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to use Bioperl module SeqFeature but the code is not working.

I have tried writing the code using Padre.

```
use Bio::SeqIO;
my $seqio_object = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "sequence.gb" );
my $seq_object = $seqio_object->next_seq;
print ref($seq_object);

for my $feat_object ($seq_object->get_SeqFeatures) {
print "primary tag: ", $feat_object->primary_tag, "\n";

for my $tag ($feat_object->get_all_tags) {
    print "  tag: ", $tag, "\n";
    for my $value ($feat_object->get_tag_values($tag)) {
        print "    value: ", $value, "\n";
    }
}
```

}

I want the file to be opened and the information in it to be displayed on the output window but its giving an exception.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any information given with the error?

Answer (score 0):

That message is given by the operating system when you provide a file name to an operation that requires the named file to exist, but it doesn't. For example, when code tries to open a file that doesn't exist for reading.

Based on the minimal information you provided, one would assume the error is from the attempt to open `sequence.gb`. If so, that means the path `sequence.gb` doesn't reference an existing file.

Keep in mind that the path `sequence.gb` means the named `sequence.gb` in the current work directory, so either you have the name wrong, and you made incorrect assumptions about the current work directory.

If you want to access a file that is found in the same directory as the script, you should use the following:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

"$RealBin/sequence.gb"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write the full path or positional path to the file

```
    -file => "/home/user/sequence.gb"
    -file => "./sequence.gb"
```

I hope this will solves your problem.
Good luck!